# What does !( ) means in data constructor?

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I am reading the source code of **Data.Map**, and I find that !() is used in the data constructor of `data Map k a`.

```
data Map k a  = Tip 
              | Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !k a !(Map k a) !(Map k a)
```

I find that the `!( )` does not affect how the patten matching against the data. In the function of mapWithKey, the patten matching is still for 5 things. So I do not consider it as a operator.

```
mapWithKey f (Bin sx kx x l r)
```

After googleing, I found that the `!( )` may be related to `-XBangPatterns` which is used for lazy evalution. Am I right ? Or is it for other purpose?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`!` in data type declarations is used to indicate strictness. If we [search for it on Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%21), we see a link to [**keyword** !](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#.21), which explains the behavior. The Report [defines](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-710004.2.1) the exact behavior.

In `data Foo = Foo ... !T ...`, the constructor `Foo` forces its argument, i.e. `` Foo ... x ... = x `seq` RealFoo ... x ... ``. where `RealFoo` is the constructor you would get without the `!`.

`{-# UNPACK #-}` is a GHC extension that means the `Size` (i.e. `Int`) is stored unboxed, directly as part of the data type.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Oh, so I get totally wrong? It is not for lazy evaluation, but for evaluating the values of the arguments. But I am not sure why the package force the strictness on the Map. Without the strictness, we can still do the searching, mapping when we are going though the map's tree

Comment: `Data.Map` is spine-strict for efficiency. Really, efficiency is the main reason people usually care about adding strictness.

Answer (score 3):

In a data constructor ! indicates the arguments are evaluated as the type is constructed. This forces functions to be evaluated and helps you control the space requirements of your application.

The [high-performance Haskell](http://www.slideshare.net/tibbe/highperformance-haskell) slides cover this in more detail.

Comment: `BangPatterns` is an extension which does something else. This is merely a strict field.